# Traverse complex json and modify Strings in place

Tags: java

I have a complex json which has nested data, a mix of String numbers, list within lists, maps within maps and so on.

I wan to go over every section of this object without having to recreate the object and find all the Strings.

Every time a String value is found, append "hello" to it.

Is this possible?

Came up with the following but this will not work.

Assigning the following won't actually replace it.

```
value = value + "hello"; // This is not going to work.
```

The complex json is not set in stone, there will be different variations,

thus just trying to traverse every possible parts of the json and find string and append "hello" to it.

Implementation where nothing is going to change since String is immutable.

```
    public void traverseAndAppendHello(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        String value = (String) obj;
        value = value + "hello"; // This is not going to work
    } else if (obj instanceof Collection) {
        Collection<?> collection = (Collection<?>) obj;
        for (Object element : collection) {
            traverseAndAppendHello(element);
        }
    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) obj;
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            traverseAndAppendHello(value);
        }
    } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] array = (Object[]) obj;
        for (Object o : array) {
            traverseAndAppendHello(o);
        }
    } else if (obj instanceof MyCustomObjectBeingTraversed) {
        Map map = mapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
        traverseAndAppendHello(map);
    }
    // move on to next steps if other types found like boolean and Number. 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you always need a reference to the structure that the `String` is inside of. The reason is that `String`s are immutable and you need to re-write the reference to the new value in the "surrounding" structure. In case of a `Collection` you need to re`set` that specific value in the collection. In case of a `Map`, you need to call `setValue` on that `Entry`.

Comment: @f1sh Wondering if I should check if obj is a String and perform the value sets during the for loops itself before I traverse again. This way I will know the key for maps and index for collections. And just remove the instanceof String check. But will end up with Unsupported Exception if I modify during the loop though when it comes to collection.